# JQuery animation issue in IE that work great in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

So I am running an animation on this site: http://www.pivot-innovation.com/index_dev.php

And everything is looking and working fine in every browser. Except of course IE. At first it was telling me that calling jquery from google had an error...so i pulled the full version of jquery locally can now I am calling that. My script is simple but it does not animate or fade or anything just in IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#left_innovation_image").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("#right_innovation_image").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("#mainImage_home").hide(); //Hide all content

    $("#left_innovation_image").fadeIn(2000); //Show first tab content
    $("#right_innovation_image").fadeIn(2000); //Show first tab content

    $("#left_innovation_image").animate({position:'absolute', top:'0px', left:'50px'}, 1000)
    $("#right_innovation_image").animate({position:'absolute', top:'0px', right:'50px'}, 1000,
    function(){

    }
    )

    $("#mainImage_home").delay(2500).fadeIn(1000); //Show first tab content

});
</script>
```

I even tried to play with the position absolute and just simply animate left like this:

```
$("#left_innovation_image").animate({'left': '+=50px'}, 1000)
```

and it still does not work or move. Any Ideas how to fix this? If not, can I write something that just tells IE to display an image and forget jQuery.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I would suggest adding semi-colons to the end of your `animate()` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `position:absolute` in animate for starters
Can you post some sample html so we can fiddle it